# Roblox Error: Attempt to index nil with 'EquippedTool' - Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

```lua
player.inventory.EquippedTool.Value = if returnValue.Inventory.EquippedTool ~= nil then returnValue.Inventory.EquippedTool else "BasicMike"
            
for _, tool in ipairs(player.inventory.OwnedTools:GetChildren()) do
    print(tool.Name)
    tool.Value = if returnValue.Inventory.Ownedtools[tool.Name] ~= nil then returnValue.Inventory.OwnedTools[tool.Name] else false
end
```

making code to save each players equipped tool data and this error came up

Comment: `player.inventory` doesn't exist. What was it supposed to be?

Comment: Might be Luau specific, but the first line is a syntax error, see http://lua-users.org/wiki/TernaryOperator on how the syntax for ternary expressions work

Answer (score 0):

Inventory?
Do you mean

```
game.Players.player.Backpack
```

Backpack is a folder that contain all players tool that have not being equipped
and If you want to find the tool player is currently holding that will be under player's Model